# Facebook OG - Adding image thats not the featured image - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image, facebook, facebook-graph-api

If you visit this page: http://www.leicesterymca.co.uk/show/?showid=3ea8f5c1-55f7-e611-80d7-00505601004c and click on the Facebook icon to share the show, you will see the image it takes is the logo of my site. I would like it to take the main show image I have.

I understand it doesn't do this because the main show image is not a featured image but an image pulled through from an XML source.

The code I have to pull this image through from the XML sources is as follows:

```
<div class="featured-image-show"><img src='<?php echo $show_img_url ?>' /></div>
```

I have found the following code for my Wordpress functions file, to add show the page featured image when I share the page using share buttons...

```
//Adding the Open Graph in the Language Attributes
function add_opengraph_doctype( $output ) {
        return $output . ' xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"';
    }
add_filter('language_attributes', 'add_opengraph_doctype');

//Lets add Open Graph Meta Info

function insert_fb_in_head() {
    global $post;
    if ( !is_singular()) //if it is not a post or a page
        return;
        echo '<meta property="fb:admins" content="YOUR USER ID"/>';
        echo '<meta property="og:title" content="' . get_the_title() . '"/>';
        echo '<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>';
        echo '<meta property="og:url" content="' . get_permalink() . '"/>';
        echo '<meta property="og:site_name" content="http://www.leicesterymca.co.uk"/>';
    if(!has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID )) { //the post does not have featured image, use a default image
        $default_image="http://example.com/image.jpg"; //replace this with a default image on your server or an image in your media library
        echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . $default_image . '"/>';
    }
    else{
        $thumbnail_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'medium' );
        echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . esc_attr( $thumbnail_src[0] ) . '"/>';
    }
    echo "
";
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'insert_fb_in_head', 5 );
```

Currently I assume this looks for the featured image and shares it, if it doesn't find a featured image it default to an image I can specify.

So my question is: How do I specify it to show the image I have in the code here instead of the featured image or even the logo...

```
<div class="featured-image-show"><img src='<?php echo $show_img_url ?>' /></div>
```

Comment: You need to specify it via `og:image` meta tag. So you first of all need to make sure that your data from the XML source is already available at that point. (Or you would need to find a hook that allows you to manipulate the meta tags at a later stage.)

Comment: Hi @Shau, give us more info: where the URL to another image is stored? Post metadata?